# Модуль для множественной регистрации

Tags: drupal, users

Подскажите модуль на друпале для регистрации 3-х групп пользователей. Т.е. вы выбираете, кем вы будете (gr1, gr2 или gr3), и в зависимости от ссылки на группу будут выводиться 3 разные поля регистрации (gr1->имя, фамилия;gr2->отчество, дата рождения и т.д.), и, соответственно, будут выводиться разные поля на странице пользователя.

P.S. Гуглом пользуюсь, сейчас ковыряю https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole , но что-то он не очень подходит, или мне не хватает мозгу.

Answer (score 1):

[Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) & [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) тупо дать путь на регистрацию для типа профиля 1... для профиля типа 2 другой путь и т. д.

OR:

[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) & [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) создать поле выбор роли в профиле юзера (стандартном), выбрать ему роль, исходя из того, какую он роль выбрал, назначить роль с помощью **rules** и скрыть или показать разные поля для разных ролей в зависимости от выбора юзера с помощью **Conditional Fields**.